# How to mount an encrypted TrueCrypt partition always in the same point?

Tags: mount, partition, truecrypt

I just formatted my external HD and divided it in two partitions: an ext4 where important information will be, and a ntfs for "compatibility" things (i.e. movies, music, etc).

I encrypted the ext4 partition with TrueCrypt but now I'm facing a problem I hadn't before: instead of mounting in `/media/DATA/` it is mounting in `/media/truecryptX`, where X is the number of virtual device selected in TrueCrypt.

I know that if I always mount the partition as device 1, the mount point will be always `/media/truecrypt1/`, but I would like to have some other point more "meaningful" like `/media/DATA/`. For example the ntfs partition is always mounted as `/media/DATANTFS/` because it isn't encrypted.

Comment: Are you mounting from `/etc/crypttab` or manually? As of 1.6.0 cryptsetup supports truecrypt. You can also use [tcplay](https://github.com/bwalex/tc-play) to mount to `/media/data`, for example and [uninstall truecrypt](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2013/01/10/truecrypt/)...

Comment: I'm mounting through TrueCrypt's GUI.

Comment: You can use `tcplay` to mount to a mountpoint of your choice; not sure in TrueCrypt, I no longer have it installed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use TC GUI, you should set some favorite volumes -- you can read more about it [here](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/favorites). It's simple. First you have to mount your volumes one by one and specify mount points:

[image]

Then you just add them to favorites:

[image]

The more you add, the bigger will be the list of favorite volumes:

[image]

Next time you want to mount them, you just have to use `Favorites` menu:

[image]

Or if you want to use a terminal, just type the following line:

```
$ truecrypt --auto-mount=favorites
```

It will mount all the favorite volumes you have on the list.

If you want to do it as a normal user, you can add that user to `truecrypt` group:

```
# groupadd truecrypt
# adduser user truecrypt
```

and set an appropriate entry in sudo config file:

```
# Users in the truecrypt group are allowed to run TrueCrypt as root.
%truecrypt ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/truecrypt
```

You should consider using LUKS instead. It's a way easier to configure every aspect of encrypted volumes.